# Haskell's Scrap Your Boilerplate (SYB) - applying transformation only once instead of everywhere

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, scrap-your-boilerplate

What's the best way to apply a transformation to a tree only once instead of `everywhere` using SYB? For instance, in the following simplified expression, there are several instances of `Var "x"`, and I want to replace the first instance with `Var "y"` only.

`data Exp = Var String
         | Val Int
         | Plus Exp Exp
         |...`

myExp = Val 5 `Plus` Var "x" `Plus` Val 5 `Plus` Var "x" ...

This can't be done using the `everywhere` combinator since it will try to transform all instances of `Var "x"` to `Var "y"`.

EDIT (after posting): Looks like `somewhere` is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a SYB beginner myself, my answer is more like a guess, but seems to work.

Combinator `somewhere` recommended by Neil Brown probably doesn't do exactly what you want. It's [defined](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/syb/0.3.7/doc/html/src/Data-Generics-Schemes.html#somewhere) as

```
-- | Apply a monadic transformation at least somewhere
somewhere :: MonadPlus m => GenericM m -> GenericM m

-- We try "f" in top-down manner, but descent into "x" when we fail
-- at the root of the term. The transformation fails if "f" fails
-- everywhere, say succeeds nowhere.
-- 
somewhere f x = f x `mplus` gmapMp (somewhere f) x
```

where

```
-- | Transformation of at least one immediate subterm does not fail 
gmapMp :: forall m. MonadPlus m => (forall d. Data d => d -> m d) -> a -> m a
```

But we need to transform *at most once*. For this it seems that `gmapMo` will be better:

```
-- | Transformation of one immediate subterm with success 
gmapMo :: forall m. MonadPlus m => (forall d. Data d => d -> m d) -> a -> m a
```

So I made my own combinator:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)
import Data.Generics.Schemes
import Data.Generics.Aliases

-- | Apply a monadic transformation once.
once :: MonadPlus m => GenericM m -> GenericM m
once f x = f x `mplus` gmapMo (once f) x
```

If the substitution fails, it returns `mzero`, otherwise it returns the substituted result. If you don't care if the substitution fails (no matches), you could use something like

```
once' :: (forall a. Data a => a -> Maybe a) -> (forall a. Data a => a -> a)
once' f x = fromMaybe x (once f x)
```

With these, we can do some replacements:

```
data Exp = Var String | Val Int | Plus Exp Exp
  deriving (Show, Typeable, Data)

myExp = Val 5 `Plus` Var "x" `Plus` Val 5 `Plus` Var "x"

replM :: (MonadPlus m) => Exp -> m Exp
replM (Var "x") = return $ Var "y"
replM t         = mzero

main = do
    -- `somewhere` doesn't do what we want:
    print $ (somewhere (mkMp replM) myExp :: Maybe Exp)

    -- returns `Just ..` if the substitution succeeds once,
    -- Nothing otherwise.
    print $ (once (mkMp replM) myExp :: Maybe Exp)
    -- performs the substitution once, if possible.
    print $ (once' (mkMp replM) myExp :: Exp)

    -- Just for kicks, this returns all possible substitutions
    -- where one `Var "x"` is replaced by `Var "y"`.
    print $ (once (mkMp replM) myExp :: [Exp])
```

Comment: To make this work on my code, I had to rewrite once as `once f x = f x \`mplus\` gmapMo (once f) x`.

Comment: @user1546806 Yes, sorry, that was a silly mistake. I'll correct the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think `somewhere (mkMp mySpecificFunction)` should do it, if you use a MonadPlus monad and make it succeed when it finds what you're looking for.

A flexible but hacky alternative is to use `everywhereM` with a State monad that can store a `Boolean` (or store `Maybe MyFunc` or whatever) and apply the transformation depending on the state being `True` or `Just myFunc` -- that way, when you are done (e.g. after applying the transformation once), you just alter the state to be `False`/`Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks, @NeilBrown. Could you elaborate the first approach a bit more? I found this [library](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/reclib/), which also uses MonadPlus to specify onetime transformation, but it does not use `somewhere`. The second approach works, but we don't want to go that route.